# Android Media player continues preperation best practice

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a remote music stream where the url changes each song.
 I don't want the user to wait for the media player preparation each time the song ends.
My idea of implementing this was to create two media player instances, and to load the next song during the play of the other media player, and when the song ends to switch between them and to prepare the next song on the one that stopped playing.

I was wondering if doing this is the best practice, or is there another way to achieve this.

Comment: That sounds like the reasonable approach if you're using the `MediaPlayer` API. In API level 16 and above you can use the `setNextMediaPlayer` method to make Android transition between the two MediaPlayers as seamlessly as possible. In older versions you can do the switch in the `onCompletionListener`.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, my app should support API 8. So, I need to implement this by myself. Changing between them when one is finished is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, I've done that like this:

```
    public MediaPlayer[] mediaPlayers;
public MediaPlayer currentMediaPlayer;
public MediaPlayer preloadMediaPlayer;
```

The you can init them:

```
    private void initMediaPlayers() {
    mediaPlayers = new MediaPlayer[MEDIA_PLAYER_COUNT];
    mediaPlayers[0] = createMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayers[1] = createMediaPlayer();
    currentMediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[0];
    preloadMediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[1];
    currentPlayerIndex = 0;
}
```

createMediaPlayer is just a helper method:

```
private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer() {
    final MediaPlayer smp = new MediaPlayer();
    smp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                       //TODO: add your code here
                    }

    });
    smp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
           //TODO: add your own error handling
           return true;
        }
    });
            //TODO: add anything else you need
    return smp;
}
```

Then if you want to swap players:

```
private void swapPlayers() {
    if (currentPlayerIndex == 0) {
        currentMediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[1];
        preloadMediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[0];
        currentPlayerIndex = 1;
    } else if (currentPlayerIndex == 1) {
        currentMediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[0];
        preloadMediaPlayer = mediaPlayers[1];
        currentPlayerIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version, you will probably want to extend MediaPlayer and add a few flags to know whether you are ready to preload (or done preloading and you're ready), etc.

But this should give you the idea.

Don't forget to release everything when you're done by calling reset/release in the mediaplayers.